React Native DateTimePicker can't apply styles for android
I need to style datetime component in react native. I am using Expo.
The datetimepicker library is installed via command:
 npx expo install u/react-native-community/datetimepicker
According to this document styling of the datetime component is possible through plugins object of app.json document. However, I get following error:

"Package "@react-native-community/datetimepicker" does not contain a valid config plugin.

Learn more: https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/#creating-a-plugin

Cannot use import statement outside a module"


The error occures after applying changes to app.json when trying to use prebuild --clean command.
Any ideas how I might be able to fix this?

Which version of @react-native-community/datetimepicker have you installed?
From the document you've linked:

To use the features documented here, you need to use version >= 8.2.0 and a Expo Development build.

